# How do I align piecewise functions?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align piecewise functions, not within the piecewise functions but the actual functions themselves. I use this piece of code but I keep getting a tonne of error messages:

```
    \begin{align}
    M(x)& = 
    \begin{displaymath}
       \left\{
         \begin{array}{lr}
           2(2x) \hspace{35pt} x < 0.5\\
           2(2 - 2x) \hspace{16pt} x > 0.5
         \end{array}
       \right.
    \end{displaymath} \\
    & =  \begin{displaymath}
       \left\{
         \begin{array}{lr}
           4x \hspace{35pt} x < 0.5\\
           4 - 4x \hspace{16pt} x > 0.5
         \end{array}
       \right.
    \end{displaymath} \\
    \end{align}
```

Comment: See [this section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#The_cases_environment) :).

Comment: Have you tried the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package? Also, you can't use a `displaymath` environment within an `align` environment.

Comment: By the way: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `cases` environment for piecewise functions ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    M(x)& = 
    \begin{cases}
       2(2x),&  x < 0.5,\\
       2(2 - 2x),& x > 0.5
    \end{cases} \\
    & =  \begin{cases}
          4x,& x < 0.5,\\
          4 - 4x,& x > 0.5
         \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say "must", there are other alternatives, including variants on the `cases` theme - but you are right that this is surely the best solution here: +1

Comment: Yeah, your are right